# Compare and return String values to a string-array in Xml Android

Tags: android

Good day, i will try to explain my problem as best as i can. i have in one of my class,  getters and setters for a string object. Now in my getString() method, i am trying to compare the string to a string-array of items in my String.xml to see if any of the elements in the string-array file matches the given string and return that matched item element in the string array.

I have something like this so far:

for setPlace():

```
public void setPlace(String place) {

this.place = place;
    }
```

for getPlace():

```
        public String getPlace() {

        //am stuck here and not sure how to compare this and return the correct item

   if(place.equals(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myPlacesArray))){

                //return context.getResources().getString();        
            }
```

my Strings.xml file:

```
<string-array name="myPlacesArray">
    <item>@string/myplace1</item>
    <item>@string/myPlace2</item>
    <item>@string/myPlace3</item>
</string-array>

<string name="myplace1">home</string>
<string name="myplace2">office</string>
<string name="myplace3">gym</string>
```

the reason i have to do this, is because it has different locales(languages) values and it would be a lot easier than writing a huge list of if/else or switch statements for different String elements and languages. Please any ideas is highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Code for getting value from String.xml and compare :

```
    String[] categoriesAndDescriptions =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myPlacesArray);
    for(String cad : categoriesAndDescriptions) {
        String categoryAndDesc = cad;
        Log.v("CategoryName", categoryAndDesc);
        if(place.equalsIgnoreCase(categoryAndDesc)){
        //Do your Stuffs here
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just loop over the returned array, doing a `place.equals` on each item in that array, and return the match when they match.

If they're sorted (they're not in this case) you could use `Arrays.binarySearch`. You could also use `Arrays.asList` and call `contains(place)` on the resulting list, which is essentially the same as looping manually.

You'd need to decide what to return if there's no match (if that's even possible).